# JS or jQuery event when page loaded from cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the 'pjax:complete' event on my paginated shop page to update selects and their options. And it works fine, but when user clicks the back button in their browser the page is loaded from cache and 'pjax:complete' doesn't work.

To which event can I add functions for starting them after the page is loaded from cache?

This is not working:

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function () {
    // code here...
});
```

Comment: Maybe have a look into [History API](https://caniuse.com/#search=History%20API) (its a native technology).

Comment: As i understand that API helps to detect changing of state, like `window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      // Do something here
    }` Thanks this is interesting, i will try it soon.

Comment: You can try `pjax:popstate`, for details see https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: @AtiqulAlam Super! Apparently this is what we need. Thanks.